# How to replace duplicates in an array with 0

Tags: c#

I have two arrays that have 20 randomly assigned elements and I need to create a method that replaces the duplicate numbers in an array with zeros but when I display the output nothing is changed.
This is the method for removing the repeating numbers. Is there a problem with the way the for loop is set up?

```
public static void RemoveDuplicates (int [] xArray){
for (int i = 0; i > xArray.Length-1; i++){
  if (xArray[i] == xArray[i+1])
    xArray[i] = 0;
  }
}
```

and this is the whole thing

```
using System;

class MainClass {
public static void Main (string[] args) {
int [] student1 = new int [20];
int [] student2 = new int [20];  
//int [] both = new int [40];
  FillArray(student1);
  FillArray(student2);

  //Console.WriteLine("---------- Unsorted ----------");

  //DisplayOutput(student1,student2);
  
  Sort2Arrays(student1,student2);

  //Console.WriteLine("---------- Sorted ----------");
  //DisplayOutput(student1,student2);

  RemoveDuplicates(student1);
  RemoveDuplicates(student2);
  DisplayOutput(student1, student2);

  Sort2Arrays(student1,student2);
  Console.WriteLine("---------- 1 and 2 no duplicates ----------");
  DisplayOutput(student1, student2);

  Console.WriteLine("done");

}//end main 

public static void FillArray (int [] xArray){
  Random rnd = new Random();
  for(int i = 0; i< xArray.Length; i++){
  xArray.SetValue (rnd.Next(80, 101),i);
  }//end for 

}//end FillArray

public static void Sort2Arrays (int [] xArray, int [] yArray){
  Array.Sort(xArray);
  Array.Sort(yArray);

}//end Sort2Arrays

public static void DisplayOutput (int [] xArray, int [] yArray){
  for(int i = 0; i< 20; i++){
  Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}",xArray.GetValue(i),yArray.GetValue(i));
  }//end for

}//end DisplayOutput

public static void RemoveDuplicates (int [] xArray){
for (int i = 0; i > xArray.Length-1; i++){
  if (xArray[i] == xArray[i+1])
    xArray[i] = 0;
  }
}


}
```

Comment: Don't use `SetValue` just `xArray[i] = 0;` and the second `if...continue` is redundant. `SetValue` is not how you set an array location, It's designed for when you don't know the type of the array

Comment: 00xy0x is the expected output

Comment: Disregards my comment, you are sorting data before calling your method, therefore `xxxyxx` input is impossible.

Comment: Be careful with SetValue. According to the documentation, `xArray.SetValue(xArray[i],0)` will assign the value of xArray[i] at index 0, not the other way around. (https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.array.setvalue?view=net-5.0#System_Array_SetValue_System_Object_System_Int32_)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your for-loop condition is wrong, not `>`:

```
for (int i = 0; i > xArray.Length - 1; i++){
```

but `<`

```
for (int i = 0; i < xArray.Length - 1; i++)
```

with your version you will never enter the loop.

May i suggest you a different way to replace the duplicates(what you actually do), which is more efficient, more readable and more reusable:

```
public static void ReplaceDuplicates<T>(IList<T> xArray, T replaceWith)
{
    HashSet<T> set = new HashSet<T>();
    for (int i = 0; i < xArray.Count; i++)
    {
        if(!set.Add(xArray[i]))
        {
            xArray[i] = replaceWith;
        }
    }
}
```

It also doesn't need to sort the collection.

You use it in this way:

```
ReplaceDuplicates(student1, 0);
ReplaceDuplicates(student2, 0);
```

Comment: Oh my god I didn't notice the sign going the wrong way. That fixed it, thank you

Comment: @nllatimo: I have edited my answer to show you a different approach for what you want

Answer (score 2):

the `>` shouldve been `<`

```
public static void RemoveDuplicates (int [] xArray){
for (int i = 0; i < xArray.Length - 2; i++){
  if (xArray[i] == xArray[i+1])
  xArray[i] = 0;
  }//end for
}//end RemoveDuplicates
```

Comment: Also this ^ (included in my solution as well).

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void RemoveDuplicates(int[] array)
{
    var foundValues = new HashSet<int>();
    
    for (var index = 0; index < array.Length; index++)
    {
        var currentValue = array[index];

        if (foundValues.Contains(currentValue))
        {
            array[index] = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            foundValues.Add(currentValue);
        }
    }
}
```